# Is it wrong to wish for Redux-driven routing, and route/URL as second class citizen?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have read the official [Redux documentation regarding React Router](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html) and investigated [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux), [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router) and [redux-little-router](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router). I also agree with the [rational for redux-little-router](https://formidable.com/blog/2016/07/11/let-the-url-do-the-talking-part-1-the-pain-of-react-router-in-redux/): React Router has strong architecture consequences on a React app, and they somehow conflict with Redux.

My feeling about routing is that it has too much importance in the React+Redux ecosystem, whereas it should be treated as a second class citizen. When designing a single page app, we often don't need URLs at all. We still support them to preserve the Web experience (SEO, bookmarking...), but we certainly don't want them to drive the app structure.

What I am thinking of:

- External navigation: a route-to-state mapping, with the classic reduced action mechanism. In other words, navigation triggers an action that is dispatched and processed by a custom reducer (with just some help for route mapping and parsing). Once the state is updated, this is React as usual. In particular, there is no mapping between routes and React components, unlike what React Router's `Route` does and a bit like [redux-little-router](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router) does.
- In app navigation: the current URL is derived from the state, a bit like the view. A kind of `renderURL` function a Redux middleware is aware of. If a state update generates no change in the URL, well, nothing happens. But if the URL is now different, the middleware reflects the change by pushing it to the history.

With this approach, there is no more `Link` component. There are only regular Redux actions and a middleware to take care of the navigation as a side effect. Actually, this solution does for navigation what React does for the DOM: a (super-straightforward) URL reconciliation, with the state as the single source of truth.

To illustrate this, consider the [Redux Todo list example](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html):

- When visiting `/SHOW_ALL`, an action containing the URL is dispatched. A regular, navigation-dedicated reducer sets `visibilityFilter` to  `VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL` in the state, possibly with some route mapping/parsing helpers. As an alternative, the navigation action could be turned into a `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` action, which is then dispatched and reduced as usual.
- A fancy `renderURL` function is registered at store creation as part of a middleware. It returns `"/" + state.visibilityFilter`. Again, some route management helpers would be welcome for real life apps.

Now there is no change in the [original Todo app](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html). We only add some new code to support a new feature.

The problem is: I can't find anything that support this vision. No article, no react-redux-something package. As a React beginner, either I am a genius or there is something I don't get. Since the later is the most likely (to my uttermost dismay), I would appreciate:

- Feedback regarding the "Redux-driven React routing", or whatever it should be named. How is it flawed?
- Hints about how I should consider Redux and routing, like relevant articles.